# How to search and delete files who contain specific string in name

Tags: delete

How can I delete every file on the system which have `something` in the name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/443830/delete-all-files-that-contain-a-particular-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Please be careful**

This following command with the parameter `-delete` deletes all the files with `something` in the name in the specified directory and in all subdirectories.

---

Open a terminal and go to the right folder:

```
cd <your_search_starts_here>
```

test with

```
find . -type f -name "*something*"
```

and delete with

```
find . -type f -name "*something*" -delete
```

Or a shorter version:

```
find <your_search_starts_here> -type f -name "*something*" -delete
```

---

For your home folder:

- **!!! first run a test**

  ```
  find ~ -type f -name "*something*"
  ```

  and than

  ```
  find ~ -type f -name "*something*" -delete
  ```

For the whole filesystem

- ***!!! first run a test !!!***

  ```
  sudo find / -type f -name "*something*"
  ```

  and test again and than delete with

  ```
  sudo find / -type f -name "*something*" -delete
  ```

Or only in the specified directory:

```
find <your_search_starts_here> -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*something*" -delete
```

---

And because you have used the tag `locate`:

The results of a search with `locate` are based on a database. This may be outdated. Start an update with `sudo updatedb`. `find` performs a true search. However, it also takes longer.

Comment: That's the problem `right folder` .. those files are all across the system and it will be pain to navigate it to each folder and delete them.

Comment: As I wrote "This command deletes all the files with `something` in the name in the specified directory and in all subdirectories."

Comment: So there is no way to say `check the system, find "files" and delete them` without to say first `in this directory` as I said is too much time consuming if I navigate to each directory where it has the file and then delete it.

Comment: Answered, read and please be careful.

Comment: Thank's let me try it. It will be long long `find....` I will post the result.

Comment: Strange.. whit `locate file` It found really a lot of that file.. but with `sudo find / -type f -name "*something*"` it found only ~10-15 results.

Comment: Also it didn't delete any file whit `-delete`. All files are still on the system

Comment: The search with `locate` is based on a database. This may be outdated. Start an update with `sudo updatedb`. `find` performs a true search. However, it also takes longer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23889/discussion-between-a-b-and-goro).